# MPC functions used on buildyourownlisp.com do not seem to work or exist

Tags: c, mpc

I am currently working through [buildyourownlisp](http://www.buildyourownlisp.com/chapter6_parsing) and really enjoy it so far, but I am currently stuck with a weird problem. The book is using the multiprecicision C library for writing grammar for the Lisp interpreter. Since I have devtools installed on my linux system I also have the mpc and libmpc packets installed.
When I run the code from the book however I run into problems with the syntax. There appears to be no `mpc_parser_t` in this library, and I couldn't even find this being used online at all.
The code I used is

```
/* Create Some Parsers */
mpc_parser_t* Number   = mpc_new("number");
mpc_parser_t* Operator = mpc_new("operator");
mpc_parser_t* Expr     = mpc_new("expr");
mpc_parser_t* Lispy    = mpc_new("lispy");

/* Define them with the following Language */
mpca_lang(MPCA_LANG_DEFAULT,
  "                                                     \
    number   : /-?[0-9]+/ ;                             \
    operator : '+' | '-' | '*' | '/' ;                  \
    expr     : <number> | '(' <operator> <expr>+ ')' ;  \
    lispy    : /^/ <operator> <expr>+ /$/ ;             \
  ",
  Number, Operator, Expr, Lispy);
```

And the compiler throws errors at me for every use of `mpc_parser_t` as well as `mpca_lang` and `MPCA_LANG_DEFAULT`. Here is an example:

```
prompt.c:8:2: error: unknown type name ‘mpc_parser_t’; did you mean ‘mp_prec_t’?
    8 |  mpc_parser_t* Number = mpc_new("number");
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |  mp_prec_t
```

I couldn't find anyone else reporting these problems but I can't see what I am doing wrong, any advice is appreciated.

Edit: The following is all of the code that I am trying to compile because  Paul Ogilvie asked me to show where I am including the file.

```
#include <mpc.h>

#ifdef _WIN32

static char buffer[2048];

char* readline(char* prompt) {
  fputs(prompt, stdout);
  fgets(buffer, 2048, stdin);
  char* cpy = malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);
  strcpy(cpy, buffer);
  cpy[strlen(cpy)-1] = '\0';
  return cpy;
}

void add_history(char* unused) {}

#else
#include <editline/readline.h>
#endif

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  
  /* Create Some Parsers */
  mpc_parser_t* Number   = mpc_new("number");
  mpc_parser_t* Operator = mpc_new("operator");
  mpc_parser_t* Expr     = mpc_new("expr");
  mpc_parser_t* Lispy    = mpc_new("lispy");
  
  /* Define them with the following Language */
  mpca_lang(MPCA_LANG_DEFAULT,
    "                                                     \
      number   : /-?[0-9]+/ ;                             \
      operator : '+' | '-' | '*' | '/' ;                  \
      expr     : <number> | '(' <operator> <expr>+ ')' ;  \
      lispy    : /^/ <operator> <expr>+ /$/ ;             \
    ",
    Number, Operator, Expr, Lispy);
  
  puts("Lispy Version 0.0.0.0.2");
  puts("Press Ctrl+c to Exit\n");
  
  while (1) {
  
    char* input = readline("lispy> ");
    add_history(input);
    
    /* Attempt to parse the user input */
    mpc_result_t r;
    if (mpc_parse("<stdin>", input, Lispy, &r)) {
      /* On success print and delete the AST */
      mpc_ast_print(r.output);
      mpc_ast_delete(r.output);
    } else {
      /* Otherwise print and delete the Error */
      mpc_err_print(r.error);
      mpc_err_delete(r.error);
    }
    
    free(input);
  }
  
  /* Undefine and delete our parsers */
  mpc_cleanup(4, Number, Operator, Expr, Lispy);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are your `#include` files? There is a difference between the compiler not knowing a definition, and the linker not finding the function.

Comment: The example says to `#include <mpc.h>` or `#include "mpc.h"`

Comment: For the relevant snippet there is `#include <mpc.h>`, the file is located in `/opt/include`.

Comment: Show where and how you include the file. The symbol is defined in the mpc.h file (line 66).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Sure, see my recent edit

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I just checked and discovered something weird, my line 66 of mpc.h is a comment and `mpc_parser_t` is not defined in this file. Maybe some sort of problem with the version? I am running manjaro, I will check if there are any updates available for these packages